# Re-arranging data from a matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I receive data with this matrix shape every month and I need to move cells into the top to display it like the desired output. Only thing I got right is the code to delete empty cells once I've moved all the text.

[image: Screen capture of original data and desired output]

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long

' Code left here to cut and paste every cell into the respective column top


  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:N32")

  rows = r.rows.Count

  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this (or you can record a macro with the following steps)

- Select a range containing the matrix you have
- Press Ctrl+G for the "Go to" command
- Click on the "Special.."  button at the bottom
- Select "Blanks" then OK
- Delete the selected cells by typing Ctrl Minus (or in Excel 2007+, Home > Cells > Delete > Delete Cells... on the Ribbon)
- Select "Shift Cells Up" then OK

Comment: I have data below also, with totals and so on, so this method shifts up everything.

Comment: You can get round this by only selecting the months where you have data. There is the same amount of data in each column so each column should shift by the same amount. You can then shift up future months manually to match the other columns. If this approach works then you can record a macro to do this